# How do you pass in a <random> RNG as a parameter of a non-template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

If I have a function, how can I pass in a C++11 random-number generator (like [std::mt19937](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)) as a parameter to a non-template function, without mandating what RNG the caller uses?

It doesn't seem like the C++11 random-number generators share a common base.
Am I forced to make the function either a template, or to mandate the use of a specific generator?

One thing I tried is to pass it in as a `std::function<int()>`, but, alas, things like std::uninform_distribution require `operator()`, `max()` and `min()` as member-functions.

If things like `std::uninform_distribution` expect and require a common interface, is there some base interface the generators inherit that I can take as a generic reference?

Comment: What are your objections to using a template parameter?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Because if it's a template function, then I have to put it in the header file (or else jump through hoops), and if I have to put it in the header file, then I have to #include the other things that function needs, slowing down build times. I'm not opposed to template functions - I use them alot! It's just in this case, it seems rather silly that there's no common interface, and apart from taking that one parameter, the entire function doesn't need to be a template at all. By being a template function, I have to reduce the number of pre-declarations in favor of #includes.

Comment: I'll just pass in std::mt19937 directly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They don't derive from a common base because they're not intended to be used polymorphically. So yes, if you need more than just `operator()` (which passing as a `std::function<std::mt19937::result_type()>` would give you), then you need to make it a function template.

---

When concepts make it into the language, we'll be able to do something like this:

```
void foo(RandomNumberEngine engine);
```

And the requirements of the concept `RandomNumberEngine` will be checked against the argument that is passed.

Comment: With regard to your comment on concepts: If `RandomNumberEngine` is a concept then `void foo(RandomNumberEngine engine);` is a template, so concepts don't enable avoiding templates if that's what's desired.

Comment: @bames53 I didn't mean to suggest it wasn't a template. My point was that it would provide a similar interface to if they were polymorphic types.